# No request bound thread error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have two spring boot services.
A and B.

From A service, I am calling B Service(Using Feign Client).
I have one request interceptor which adds custom headers to the request before sending it.

This is my interceptor:

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {


    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {       
        try {
            Object encrypyedData = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getAttribute(""headerName", 0);
            if(encrypyedData != null) {
                template.header("headerName", encrypyedData.toString());
            }else {
                System.out.println("Encrypted Data is NULL");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ankit === "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

But when I am running this code, I am getting exception : **No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.**

I have also tried adding this in Service A

```
@Bean public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
   return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

I have added this in Main Application File(file annotated with @SpringBootApplication).

Still the same issue. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're running your spring cloud feign on Hystrix.
Hystrix's default isolation mode is `thread`, so actual HTTP request will be called on the different thread that is managed by hystrix. And `HeaderInterceptor` also run on that thread.

But, you are accessing `RequestContextHolder` and it is using ThreadLocal. That is probably the reason for your error.

Try to use one of the the below properties on A service.

It will disable hystrix for feign.

```
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: false
```

Or, you can just change isolation mode of your hystrix like below.

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: SEMAPHORE
```

If it works, you need to choose the way that you apply to. Just disable hystrix or change isolation strategy or just passing attribute via another way.

Comment: No i am not using hystrix. but i am using rxjava. that is what causing the issue since it is not creating new threads and using the old threads.